# syncing jquery actions with image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-processing

I have created a simple image gallery, and want to make the colors of the document change based on the colors of the active image. to do this, I am using [colorThief.js](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/)

My issue is that I am using black and white versions of the images for all non-active images, and the active image is reloaded with the colored version on every click.
after porforming this change, the switchColors function stopped working properly (only works when an already active image is being clicked.
I think this has something to do with the image load, but trying to fix it by using **.load()** with a callback didn't work.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
var currentId = 0;
var id;
var stageMargin = $('body').width()/2;
    stageMargin -= $('#0>img').width()/2;
$('#stage').css('margin-left', stageMargin+'px');

var switchColors = function(image) {
    var color = colorThief.getColor(image, 5);
    var palette = colorThief.getPalette(image, 10, 5);

    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)
    randomColor = palette[num];

    randomColor = $.xcolor.complementary(randomColor).getArray();

    perform(color, randomColor);
};

var perform = function(color, randomColor){
    $('h1').css('color', 'rgb('+randomColor[0]+','+randomColor[1]+','+randomColor[2]+')');
    $('h2').css('color', 'rgb('+randomColor[0]+','+randomColor[1]+','+randomColor[2]+')');
    $('strong').css('color', 'rgb('+randomColor[0]+','+randomColor[1]+','+randomColor[2]+')');

    $('body').css('background-color', 'rgb('+color[0]+','+color[1]+','+color[2]+')');
};

var organizeStage = function(id){
    var $this;

    $('div.piece').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);

        if($this.hasClass('center')){
            $this.children('img').attr('src', bank[$this.attr('id')].image_bw);
        }

        if($this.attr('id')<id){
            $this.removeClass('right center');
            $this.addClass('left');
        }
        else if($this.attr('id')>id){
            $this.removeClass('left center');
            $this.addClass('right'); 
        }
        else{
            $this.removeClass('right left');
            $this .addClass('center');

            $this.children('img').attr('src', bank[$this.attr('id')].image);
            $('h2')[0].innerHTML = '<strong style="'+$('#tester').attr('style')+'">'+bank[$this.attr('id')].titleText+'</strong> ~ '+bank[$this.attr('id')].typeText;
        }
    });

    stageMargin = $('body').width()/2;
    stageMargin -= $('#'+id+'>img').width()/2;
    stageMargin -= 100*id;
    $('#stage').css('margin-left', stageMargin+'px');
};

$('.piece img').on('click', function(event){
    id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    if(id != currentId){
        organizeStage(id);
        currentId = id;
    }

    switchColors($('.piece.center img')[0]);

});
```

and this is the structure of the gallery HTML:

```
<section id="stage">
    <div id="0" class="piece center">
        <img src="images/0_bw.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="1" class="piece right">
        <img src="images/1_bw.jpg">
    </div>
            . 
            .
            .
</section>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: may I know what is `xcolor` in  `randomColor = $.xcolor.complementary(randomColor).getArray();` ?

Comment: also what is `bank` variable for?

Comment: xcolor (http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/) is a jquery plugin for color manipulation.
and the bank variable is an object array for storing the data for each  piece in the gallery (image, image_bw, titleText, typeText).

Comment: ok, can you provide value for `bank` variable?

Comment: it holds strings - image and image_bw are paths for the images and the others are plain text. the exact values are not important, the whole thing works except for the color change when an image that isnt centered is clicked. the image changes accordingly, but the colors stay the same. (i did find that there is an error with the canvas that colorThief is trying to create).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for this..
I tried using load() again and it worked. i guess last time I didnt use $(this) properly.

Dharmang- thanks for your time!